# Hard coding Proxy in Java for connecting to specific URL

Tags: java, web-services, proxy, apache-axis

I have a web app  which has to connect to external Web Services (using Axis client). I have to perform 2 things:

- allow the webapp to go communicate externally using a given HTTP proxy (to authorize the WS clients)
- use a direct connection when we perform a local call through a URI like

  `http://localhost:7001/webApp/getImg?id=22`

Note that it works like a charm if we use the system properties (http.proxyHost, etc.) instead of the ProxySelector.

But thing is then all the local calls are routed to the Proxy Server, which I dont want.

So, just a simple question - how to implement a `ProxySelector` which performs in the same way as when using proxy system properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the system properties by also setting `http.nonProxyHosts=localhost`.  If you want to do it with a `ProxySelector` then try something like this

```
final Proxy PROXY = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
  new InetSocketAddress("my.proxy.server", 8080));
ProxySelector.setDefault(new ProxySelector() {
  public List<Proxy> select(URI u) {
    if(u != null && !"localhost".equals(u.getHost())) {
      return Arrays.asList(PROXY, Proxy.NO_PROXY);
    }
    else {
      return Collections.singletonList(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
    }
  }

  public void connectFailed(URI u, SocketAddress sa, IOException e) {
    // do nothing
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Ian,
The thing is I am using two webservices in my Java Application.
1.) which connects to external website using HTTPS(Proxy Server Required)
2.) the other connects to internal website over HTTP(the other app is not on localhost..its on some other server 10.24.240.21

Now I use 
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX");//PROXY ADDRESS
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3128");      //PROXY PORT

How do I do such that for 2nd webservice it does not use Proxy Server